# Fullscreen menu fade won't work with svg and image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, fullscreen

I have been trying to make a fullscreen menu toggle with smooth fade in and out.

That works fine with all elements except for svg elements and picture.

Basically when you click on the menu burger you can clearly see the image and the svg icons not fading out, everything else does, but not these elements.

At first I thought it could be a z-index related problem and changed the numbers around but nothing worked.

I have been trying to find information about this for days but can't find anything on it.

I would highly appreciate your help on this, thank you.

[Heres my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsrsrs/ubpmmqnv/4/)

And code:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

    for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var toggle = toggles[i];
        toggleHandler(toggle);
    };

    function toggleHandler(toggle) {
        toggle.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") || $("#testMenu").fadeOut(300) : this.classList.add("is-active") || $("#testMenu").fadeIn(300);
        });
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because menu container is listed before image in source so it has lower index in z axis. Make `#testMenu` on the top with `z-index` and `position:relative`

```
 <nav id="testMenu" style="display: none; z-index: 1000; position: relative;">
```

Answer (score 1):

To control the `z-index`, the element must have a stacking order, like declaring a `position`.

> When you introduce the position property into the mix, any positioned elements (and their children) are displayed in front of any non-positioned elements.

Try for example, changing this:

```
#contact {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  ...
}
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubpmmqnv/5/)

Comment: Thanks Lionel! very kind of you

Comment: Glad it helps you. `z-index` sometimes is a mess.